# SonataUserBundle can't login

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I'm facing an error with SonataUserBundle. All is well configured.
I use a custom entity for User and Group but nothing complicated (just add some string informations in the table)

When i try to login on /admin with a user create trough console i got this error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.name AS name_1, t0.roles AS roles_2, t0.id AS id_3 FROM group t0 INNER JOIN user_group ON t0.id = user_group.group_id WHERE user_group.user_id = ?' with params [1]:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Erreur de syntaxe près de 'group t0 INNER JOIN user_group ON t0.id = user_group.group_id WHERE user_group.u' à la ligne 1
```

I already checked the configuration seems good, entity are ok too ...

Is someone else facing this error too ?

Thank you for your help,

Have a nice day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was my fault
I named the table group but it's reserved ... 
Works now after changing the name